# React Navigation (5+) navigation.addListener() in Class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add a Listener `beforeRemove` to a navigation to prevent the user from going back.
Then they get an `alert` to proceed or discard.
I followed the [tutorial from reactnaviagtion.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/) but this is in an **functional Component**.
In my Case its an react-native Class-Component.
I can easily call the function over the props:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.addListener("beforeRemove", (e) =>{  
        console.log("beforeRemoveTriggered");
        this.state.SomeVariablesToCheckIfGameStarted

        Alert.alert(..., onPress: ()=> this.props.navigation.dispatch(e.data.action));
    }
}
```

The `console.log` is no problem but I can't call the state inside of the callback.

```
beforeRemoveTriggered
```

But after that I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.someVariablesToCheckIfGameStarted`)
- node_modules\...
```

My Guess is that you cant call the state inside of the listener-callback.
But this is neccessary for the app function so i cant "just dont use the state".

BTW a workaround with `useEffect` would be accetable but is not preferred.
This may have a simple solution which is not specific with react-navigation or react-native but javascript.

Any tips would be helpful, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: because the state is undefined, And more important, what you want to do with the state? you are just calling it, which is not available. Probably you should add `if(!this.state.SomeVariablesToCheckIfGameStarted) return;`

Comment: No i can call the state in the "normal" componentDidMount without any issues. The Question is how to access the state inside of  callback

Comment: Ok let's try; In the callback function instead of accessing state, call another function that there you access/check state.

Comment: Should the function be in the class Component? Like this.myFunction()? And then return this.state or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my answer...
Maybe but just maybe I called `this.props` instead of `this.state`
And maybe after this discovery everything works as it should be...
I`m sorry to everyone I bothered figuring out what the solution is!